# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to find from result of another find but getting this error 
here is code snippet:

```
soup =BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
gameArea = soup.find("div", {"id": "gamefilearea"})
gameObject = gameArea.find("object")
```

html in gameArea is

```
<section id="gamearea">   
<div id="gamefilearea" class="" style="height:424px;">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdowns.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="585" height="424" id="gamefile" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="movie" value="http://cache.games.com/files/games/17971.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="window">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false">
    <param name="allowfullscreeninteractive" value="false">
    <param name="fullScreenAspectRatio" value="">
    <param name="quality" value="">
    <param name="play" value="false">
    <param name="loop" value="false">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="flashvars" value="gameID=17971">
    <param name="hasPriority" value="true">
    <embed src="http://games.com/files/games/17971.swf?v=1456132501" quality="high" width="585" height="424" id="gamefileEmbed" name="gamefile" align="middle" wmode="window" allowfullscreen="false" allowfullscreeninteractive="false" fullscreenaspectratio="" play="false" loop="false" menu="false" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="gameID=17971" haspriority="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
</div>
<script>
    var removeAdSwf = function() {
        startPlayCounter();
        jQuery('#afg_preloader').remove();
        jQuery('#gamefilearea').removeClass('afg-running prestitial-running');
    };
    var noAdsReturned = function () {removeAdSwf();};
</script>
```

from here trying to pick object element

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What's your html source code? Does it really have a `div` tag which's `id` is `gamefilearea`?

Comment: updated html in question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it out.
In my case find operation were being executed in loop and in few cases first find operation returned None because of which second find returned error.

Thanks for help